# Shutdown an SimpleXMLRPCServer server in python

Tags: python, shutdown, simplexmlrpcserver

Currently I am writing an application using the SimpleXMLRPCServer module in Python.

The basic aim of this application is to keep running on a server and keep checking a Queue for any task. If it encounters any new request in the Queue, serve the request.

Snapshot of what I am trying to do :

class MyClass():

```
"""
This class will have methods which will be exposed to the clients
"""
def __init__(self):
    taskQ = Queue.Queue()

def do_some_task(self):
    while True:
         logging.info("Checking the Queue for any Tasks..")
         task = taskQ.get()
         # Do some processing based on the availability of some task
```

## Main

if **name** == "**main**":

```
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer((socket.gethostname(), Port)
classObj = MyClass()
rpcserver.register_function(classObj.do_some_task)
rpcserver.serve_forever()
```

Once the server is started it remains in the loop forever inside do_some_task method to keep checking the Queue for any task. This is what i wanted to achieve.  But now i want to gracefully shutdown the server. In this case i am unable to shutdown the server.

Till now I have Tried using a global flag STOP_SERVER for 'True' and checking its status in the do_some_task while loop to get out of it and stop the server. But no help.

Tried using SHUTDOWN() method of the SimpleXMLRPCServer but it seems it is getting into a infinite loop of somekind.

Could you suggest some proper way to gracefully shutdown the server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the `shutdown()` docstring: _„Blocks until the loop has finished. This must be called while serve_forever() is running in another thread, or it will deadlock.“_

Comment: @BlackJack With `serve_forever()` running in another thread, catching a signal and running `shutdown()` does nothing...

Answer (score 4):

You should use `handle_request()` instead of `serve_forever()` if you want to close it manualy. Because `SimpleXMLRPCServer` is implemented as a single thread and the `serve_forever()` will make the server instance run into an infinite loop.

You can refer to this [article](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/114579/). This is an example cited from there:

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import *

class MyServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer):

    def serve_forever(self):
        self.quit = 0
        while not self.quit:
            self.handle_request()


def kill():
    server.quit = 1
    return 1


server = MyServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000))
server.register_function(kill)

server.serve_forever()
```

By using `handle_request()`, this code use a state variable `self.quit` to indicate whether to quit the infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

The `serve_forever` function is inherited from a base class in the [socketserver](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/socketserver.py) module called `BaseServer`. If you look at this fucntion you'll see it has an attribute called `__shutdown_request`, and this can be used to break the serving while loop. Because of the double underscore you'll have to access the variable with its mangled name: `_BaseServer__shutdown_request`.

Putting that all together you can make a very simple quit function as follows:

```python
from xmlrpc.server import SimpleXMLRPCServer

class MyXMLRPCServer(SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.register_function(self.quit)
    
    def quit(self):
        self._BaseServer__shutdown_request = True
        return 0
```